# SlimSelect + Angular 6

Tags: typescript, angular-6, component

Olá, é a primeira vez que utilizo o SlimSelect e estou com dificuldades em fazer funcionar.

Criei um component apenas para test chamado de 'AddConta' e em seu método 'ngOnInit()', coloquei o que a documentação do SlimSelect pedia. Exatamente como mostra a foto abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E no meu HTML criei o select como mostrado abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

***ERROR Error: Could not find select element***

Alguém sabe me ajudar?
Agradeço desde já...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se conseguiu resolver, mas faltou colocar o definidor do elemento, no caso aí um `id` **#**.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import SlimSelect from 'slim-select';

@Component({
  selector: 'add-conta',
  templateUrl: './add.conta.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add.conta.css']
})

export class addConta implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit(): void {
    new SlimSelect({
      select: '#single'
    })
  }
}
```